# array_search not showing results with ftp_rawlist

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to search for files which are uploaded or modified by certain month in the FTP server. I tried `ftp_rawlist()` to store details about all the files on the server and used `array_search()` to search that array for rows which contain the name of the month, but it's not showing any results, not even an error. Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
$buff = ftp_rawlist($ftp_conn, '/');

// $buff now contains (checked via var_dump())
// array(20) {
//   [0]=> string(64) "drwxr-xr-x 3 4664210 15000 4096 Aug 19 15:09 .Archived"
//   [1]=> string(66) "…"
// }

echo array_search("Aug" ,$buff);
```

Answer (score 0):

`array_search` will only return identical matches, so unless the value is exactly "*Aug*" and only "*Aug*", it will return no match.

Additionally, `array_search` will **only return one value**, so even if it would work to search for part of a string, only the first match would be returned even if there was multiple matching values.

To search the array, use the following code:

```
foreach ($buff as $array_value) {
  if (strpos($array_value, "Aug") !== false) {
    // found
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andre, when I do var_dump($buff); I get something like this: 

array(20) { [0]=> string(64) "drwxr-xr-x 3 4664210 15000 4096 Aug 19 15:09 .Archived" [1]=> string(66).....

I plan to use a loop to find all files created or modified by each month, for example Aug. Do you have any suggestion how can I search all values/arrays containing Aug in them?

Comment: Use `strpos` to search for occurrences: `strpos($array_value, "Aug");`
http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: Thanks again Andre. I tried strops($buff, "Aug"); but it's giving me this error:

Warning: strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given  on line 49

Comment: You seem to have inputted the entire array, you need to input the array value only (so loop through with a foreach)

`foreach($buff as $array_value){ strpos($array_value, "Aug")`

Answer (score -1):

try with:

```
$buff = ftp_rawlist($ftp_conn, '/');

print_r(array_search("Aug" ,$buff));
```

Comment: Thanks mmxx, but it didn't work either :( No results / No errors
I also tried in_array, and it's not showing results either. The only way I checked that ftp_rawlist is working, by using this code < var_dump($buff); > and it shows result something like this:

array(20) { [0]=> string(64) "drwxr-xr-x 3 4664210 15000 4096 Aug 19 15:09 .Archived" [1]=> string(66)........